# How can I send an invitation request using the Facebook API?

Tags: c#, facebook

I would like to send an invitation request from my Facebook application written in C#.

Here is what I tried:

```
_fbService.API.notifications.sendEmail(DataList1.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString(),"Invitation to play a game", "You are invited to play the game","");
```

This does not work, it only sends a notification, not a request.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried taking a look at facebook.codeplex.com/. it may be of help in answering your question as to how to send a request, and may be a different approach to use to simplify the api for use with .net.

Comment: It's not useful i have searched over it and no solution

Comment: Which .NET Facebook API are you using?

Comment: I am using .Net2008 to integrate with facebook API  using C# language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking how you can send invitations to users who have not authorized your application (i.e. not inviting your application users to use a new feature or participate in an activity), then you can't with the API.

From the API documentation - [Notifications.sendEmail](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/notifications.sendEmail/):

> Sends an email to the specified users, who have both authorized your application and granted it the email extended permission.

The API function that did allow this was [Notifications.sendRequest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/notifications.sendRequest/) but it has been disabled, perhaps due to consideration of abuse and security. See the documentation for the alternative.